# Maven Profile for Spring Boot App on Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app that I d like to deploy on Google app engine using the app engine maven plugin.

Everything works fine except I cannot find a way that Google app engine loads the correct application.properties file for the spring boot app.

I have application-prod.properties, application-default.properties and application-test.properties. Locally I can easily choose which environment/profile to start using for example

```
mvn appengine:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

But when I try to do the same for the deploy job, like

```
mvn appengine:deploy -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

That does not work. It does not load application-prod.properties but falls back to application-default.properties.

Do I missunderstand something or should that work? If that won't work since Google app engine just starts the war without passing in any param, is there a way to define environment variables for the app/service on Google where I can store stuff like database url and credentials that are environment specific?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: To be clear, you're using Spring profiles, not Maven profiles. Those are two completely different things. Maven profiles work at build type, whereas Spring profiles work at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

If using **App Engine flexible environment**, in your `app.yaml` add the following

```
env_variables:
    JAVA_USER_OPTS: '-Dspring.profiles.active=prod'
```

This will be added to the JVM start command by the runtime. See [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/openjdk-runtime#entry-point-features) for the openjdk-runtime. By default, your app is using the jetty-runtime, which inherits the options from the openjdk-runtime.

If using **App Engine standard environment**, in your `appengine-web.xml` add the following:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="spring.profiles.active" value="prod" />
</system-properties>
```

Comment: If you are deploying a Spring Boot app in the JAR packaging, you will actually be using the opendjk-runtime directly.

Comment: I am using spring profiles and I only have a appengine-web.xml file since I use standard environment and maven appengine plugin. Is there a way to make sure that for a given app on appengine the spring profile "prod" is added as a start param?

Comment: In App Engine standard with the appengine-web.xml, it's slightly different. I updated my answer with those instructions as well.

Comment: If we had say, "alpha" and "prod" spring profiles (Both uses GAE standard) and we wanted to set specific values for some properties. How would we achieve that using a single appengine-web.xml file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to set a property for a specific profile, you would do it there, if you want to set a property regardless of the profile, you would do it in <system-properties>.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers did not work for me.

Instead (because I am using app.yaml instead of app-engine.xml) I added the following two lines to my app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "myProfileName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `jvmFlags` parameter for starting your application with the desired property, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#development_server_goals

```
<jvmFlags>
  <jvmFlag>-Dspring.profiles.active=prod</jvmFlag>
</jvmFlags>
```

Comment: Thx for your feedback. And where should I put those jvmFlags? appengine-web.xml? But then again, how can I have multiple environments? appengine-web.xml would then be different for every environment, right?

Comment: These are maven settings for the plugin, so in your pom you would need to add a configuration block for that plugin and add these there.

Comment: I just added it to the plugin configuration like:
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Dspring.profiles.active=prod</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
But still application-default.properties instead of application-prod.properties is loaded.
Any ideas?

Comment: Run the command with a -X and you should be able to see which arguments it starts the jar with hopefully. It might not be correctly picking up the plugin definition as well so check the properties match between the debug output and your pom.